# Does TensorFlow Quantum tfq.convert_to_tensor work on custom gates?

Tags: programming, cirq, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, tfq, quantum-neural-network

I'm trying to use [Cirq](https://quantumai.google/cirq) with [TensorFlow Quantum](https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum) to simulate a variational quantum classifier. There's a [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/tutorials/mnist) on the TFQ website on building a quantum neural network to classify a simplified version of MNIST, which I've been using for reference.

The classifier that I'm building requires building my own [custom gates](https://quantumai.google/cirq/custom_gates).

After encoding the data as quantum circuits, the next step is to convert these Cirq circuits to tensors using [`tfq.convert_to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/api_docs/python/tfq/convert_to_tensor).

I've found that this function works fine for any built-in Cirq gates, but when I pass my own custom gate as the argument, I get `ValueError: Cannot serialize op <__main__.Custom_Gate object at...`

Here's some watered down code that gives the gist of my attempts:

```
def simple_func(x):
    return x*cirq.z

class Custom_Gate(cirq.Gate):
    def __init__(self, x, n):
        self.x = x
        self.n = n
    def _unitary_(self):
        return simple_func(self.x)
    def _num_qubits_(self):
        return self.n
    def _circuit_diagram_info_(self, args: 'cirq.CircuitDiagramInfoArgs'):
        return ['U']

x = 3
n = 1
U = Custom_Gate(x, n)
q0 = cirq.GridQubit(0, 0)
test_circuit = cirq.Circuit()
test_circuit.append(U.on(q0))
SVGCircuit(test_circuit)

tfq.convert_to_tensor([test_circuit])
```

Am I making a mistake somewhere? Or does `tfq.convert_to_tensor` just not work for custom gates?

Thank you.

Comment: `_unitary_` instead of `__unitary__`? Does `cirq.unitary(gate)` work on it?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. Michael pointed out the larger problem below.

Comment: @ Craig_Gidney Were you able to Serializing custom gates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the engineer who looks after TensorFlow Quantum. Serializing custom gates is not supported. There is an active issue on the GitHub here: https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/issues/354 . A quick workaround would be to try and determine the gate decomposition for your custom gate in terms of `tfq.util.get_supported_gates` gate instances. A good place to start might be the [cirq.kak_decomposition](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/cirq.kak_decomposition.html).

Michael